# Getting issue while using .framework which have .a static library inside it

Tags: ios, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I have `.framework` file which was working prior including another `.a/.framework` files in it.

My framework build successfully but after adding my `.framework` file to another project it is not working.

After adding other `.a` and `.framework` file in my frameworks build phases, I am getting this error.

```
0  0x103014342  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x10307d28e  ld::tool::OutputFile::addressOf(ld::Internal const&, ld::Fixup const*, ld::Atom const**) + 262
2  0x10307ef54  ld::tool::OutputFile::applyFixUps(ld::Internal&, unsigned long long, ld::Atom const*, unsigned char*) + 3712
3  0x103083693  ld::tool::OutputFile::writeAtoms(ld::Internal&, unsigned char*) + 489
4  0x10307c59e  ld::tool::OutputFile::writeOutputFile(ld::Internal&) + 818
5  0x10307669c  ld::tool::OutputFile::write(ld::Internal&) + 178
6  0x1030151c0  main + 1164
7  0x7fff8d04c5ad  start + 1
A linker snapshot was created at:
/tmp/SDKsIntegrated_Test-2016-03-01-190200.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_mode == modeFinalAddress), function finalAddress, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ld64/ld64-253.9/src/ld/ld.hpp, line 749.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please note before adding other `.a` and `.framework` files it is working.

Note: I'm doing the almost same thing appodeal.com does.
Thanks community.

Comment: Answers given here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276917/ld-warning-section-data-objc-imageinfo-data-has-unexpectedly-large-size

Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683877/xcode-4-4-clang-error-linker-failed), the same problem was solved by changing the "Strip Style" from "All Symbols" to "Non-Global Symbols", allowing the Global Symbols to be used in categories.